# Regex match 0\n but not 0\.+

Tags: regex, perl

I'll expand my original question:
I want to filter strings that ends with a "0" but not filter strings that look like "0.123". To do that I'm looking at 0 and then end of line.
Example:
"value_x 0"
"value_y 0.123"

I'm using:
    ^\S+\s+0$

but somehow this matches also "0.123`.

Why the ending `$` doesn't avoid the 2nd case? how can I fix that?

Comment: I think it does not match your value. See https://regex101.com/r/QIKNxj/1

Comment: Can you provide a full code sample that illustrates the issue? You pattern explicitly asks for at least one whitespace (`\s+`), so I think it cannot match "0.123".

Answer (score 0):

Anything that ends with a zero !! So all you need to check is if it ends with a zero . The regex can be 0$ .

Comment: That will also match strings that end with `0` followed by a newline. To avoid that, use `\z` instead of `$`. It also doubtful that it answers the OP's (unclear) question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a `0` by itself at the end, you may be looking for a word boundary.  Like this:

`\b0$`

You can read more about word boundaries here:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

If you simply want a 0 with a space before it, try this:

`\s0$`

As per `The fourth bird`'s comment, the regex you have *should* *not* be matching your sample text.

Comment: That will also match strings that end with `0` followed by a newline. To avoid that, use `\z` instead of `$`.

Comment: @ikegami interesting! I did not know that!